# Duplicate data in automatic report creation using OPENPYXL

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new to Python programming and I'm making an automatic report with this code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()


df = pd.read_csv("Data_cruda.csv")
list_df = list(df)

ws = wb.active
ws.append(list_df)
wb.save("Report.xlsx")



def reporteador(año, mes, dia):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        df = pd.read_csv("Data_cruda.csv")
        X = df.loc[0]
        X_list = list(X)
        ws.append(X_list)
        wb.save("Report_" + str(año) + str(mes) + str(dia) + ".xlsx")
        Hoy = datetime.datetime.now()
        if Hoy.second == 1 :
            break
while True:
    Now = datetime.datetime.now()
    reporteador(Now.year, Now.month, Now.day)

while True:
    Now = datetime.datetime.now()
    reporteador(Now.year, Now.month, Now.day)
```

The problem is that in each Excel that I generate per minute I get the data from the previous Excel and it is stacking when I need unique data for each report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-initialize the `Workbook` instance upon every loop

```
def reporteador(año, mes, dia):
    while True:
       # Add this 2 lines:
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        # ws.append(list_df)  # Add this if you want to have the same first row

        # Everything else the same
```